# Wordpress PHP memory limit is -1

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-limit

While checking my wordpress site, I have realised that on site health both "PHP memory limit" and "Max input time" are shown as "-1".
If I am not mistaken this would mean that it can use all the PHP memory it wants to. Nonetheless, I have not set this memory limit, and when trying to set it in the wp-config file as 40MB, which is the standard, the value does not change. I have checked and I have no php.ini file nor .htaccess defining this value.

Comment: What do you use to run your wordpress website?

Comment: A. Please follow the process:

Add test.php file in a route where wp-config.php existing.
Add function phpinfo() in that test.php file with php definition tags.
Check this test file from the website Or server path. Example: Server Path: https:\www.example.com\test.php Or localhost path http::\localhost\wordpress_folder\test.php
Here all information available related to your php server. You can check the file php.ini there.
B. You can also add this function into wp-config: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

Answer (score 0):

If your website is on a live server, log into cpanel (assuming that is what you're using). Look for php selector or multi-php editor, You should see the option to edit memory limit and Max input time.

If you don't see php selector or multi-php editor, then you'll have to contact your host to edit it for you.

Answer (score 0):

A. Please follow the process:

1. Add test.php file in a route where wp-config.php existing.
2. Add function phpinfo() in that test.php file with php definition tags.
3. Check this test file from the website Or server path.
   Example:
   Server Path: https:\www.example.com\test.php
   Or localhost path http::\localhost\wordpress_folder\test.php
4. Here all information available related to your php server. You can check the file php.ini there.

B. You can also add this function into wp-config:
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the Same issue. Now I have resolved by that below reference.

Please follow this :

https://slicedinvoices.com/question/increase-php-memory-limit/